# Disable keyboard on UITextField on edit

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker, iphone-softkeyboard

Since when I click the UITextField the date picker is showing along with the keyboard, I want to hide the key board operation  on dob-text field?Here my code

```
- (void)removeViews:(id)object 
    {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:9] removeFromSuperview];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:11] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    - (void)dismissDatePicker:(id)sender 
    {
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44);
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveOut" context:nil];
    [self.view viewWithTag:9].alpha = 0;
    [self.view viewWithTag:10].frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    [self.view viewWithTag:11].frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeViews:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (IBAction)but 
    {
    //[eventText resignFirstResponder];
    [dob resignFirstResponder];


    if ([self.view viewWithTag:9]) 
    {
        return;
    }
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

    UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds ];
    darkView.alpha = 0;
    darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    darkView.tag = 9;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] ;
    [darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.view addSubview:darkView];

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)] ;
    datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.tag = 10;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)] ;
    toolBar.tag = 11;
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] ;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] ;
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    darkView.alpha = 0.5;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateText:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //_dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
    //dateText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
    // [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

    //[self.tableview reloadData];

    }

I added the resignfirstresponder also,since its showing the same error

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return [txt1 resignFirstResponder];//dob textfield
    }
```

[image]

Comment: on textFielBeginEditing, just resign Your keyboard and load picker

Answer (score 6):

Use UITextField's delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   if(textField == dob-text )
     //load picker here
     return NO; //hide keyboard
   else
     return YES; //show keyboard
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to set the UIPickerView as the [`inputView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW54) for the [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).

And you can set the `UIToolBar` as the [`inputAccessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW54) of the  [`inputView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW54).
This way iOS will handle the displaying of all UIPickView.

Just set the properties top the correct views:

```
self.dateTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
self.dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.inputToolbar;
```

---

On another note, getting views with `viewWithTag:` methods means that the you are looping thru  all the views. Why not create properties for these views. It will be less messy and might be faster.

Comment: can yu explain with my coding

Answer (score 0):

try in textFieldDidBeginEditing

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    datePicker.hidden = NO;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a textfield should not have a popover - neither picker nor popover nor anything
Best solution would be to put a button - type custom - set image like a date selector image and add selector - in that case you would n't have any issues w.r.t textfields popover and the   look would be good as well and you can customize it as per your requirement.